# fab <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>: No speakable text present | Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, fatal-error, mobile-application

I have this error while running my project, I'm using this XML code for the Floating button, it presents ***fab <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>: No speakable text present*** error.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/ToolBar"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBar"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/faby" />
```

---

As well as, I aimed to have interaction when clicking on floating button. So, I did this Java code to do the interaction.

```
            Button fab;
            fab = findViewById(R.id.faby);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                replaceFragement(new Home());
            }
       });
```

However, it present Fatal Exceptions as presented in the figure [Fatal error while interacting Floating Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qTAD.png).

**I tried to fix it by two ways:**

1. **changing on Gradle code.**
2. **Remove interaction.**

Note that, I'm using type of XML.

```
<android.support.******>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new so sorry if my answer is slightly incorrect.

the first image with the error of "No speakable text" is because you don't have a readable label in the fabs (floating action button) XML block. I think it has to do with your ID name or not having a contentdescription attribute, but I'm not as knowledgeable in XML. you can put this in the block as well to stop the error, tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck".

[ignore suppression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ors.png)

For the fab, you need to make sure the variable type is FloatingActionButton instead of Button. It should work now, if not let us know with more information like a screenshot of the entire error.

[fab variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bQc3.png)